# my onclick function overlapped with submit handler

Tags: reactjs

when i put onClick event the form does not validate and if i delete onClick event the form does not want to submit

so recently i just start a new project with kendo react. on this project i tried to create customize grid where i can add new lines, edit or remove.

```
<form style={{ width: '1000px' }} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                    <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                        <div className="k-animation-container">
                            <DropDownList
                                defaultValue={this.state.productInEdit.Programto || ''}
                                onChange={this.onDialogInputChange}
                                name="Programto"
                                required={true}
                                data={this.prog}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row" >
                    <DialogActionsBar>
                        <Button
                            className="k-button"
                            onClick={this.props.cancel}
                        >
                            Cancel
                            </Button>
                        <Button className="mt-3" type="submit" primary={true} onClick={this.props.save} > Save </Button>

                    </DialogActionsBar>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and this is the event for validation

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ success: true });
    setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ success: false }); }, 3000);
}
```

and submit code i create it on different page, so i need to call the event with this.props.save;

```
save = () => {
    const dataItem = this.state.productInEdit;
    const products = this.state.products.slice();

    if (dataItem.ProductID === undefined) {
        products.unshift(this.newProduct(dataItem));
    } else {
        const index = products.findIndex(p => p.ProductID === dataItem.ProductID);
        products.splice(index, 1, dataItem);
    }

    this.setState({
        products: products,
        productInEdit: undefined
    });


}
```

i tried to call save event inside the handleSubmit but still not working

Comment: You should only have the `onSubmit` handler for the form and use that to validate **and** then save if the data is valid. Forms can be submitted in alternative ways and not just by clicking on the submit button.

Comment: any suggestion how to submit the form beside using `onClick` event?

Comment: Clicking on the `onClick` event will submit the form and therefore trigger the `onSubmit` event. However tabbing to the submit button and pressing enter will also submit the form and trigger the `onSubmit` event but will not necessarily trigger the `onClick` event (because the button was not technically clicked). Therefore the `onSubmit` event is all you need to handle in order to deal with all ways of submitting a form.